# jQuery bindings won't work in this particular form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii2

I'm currently working on a web app in Yii2 and I've built the following form within a model:

**`_formConnectModal.php`**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="connect-workflow-step-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Connect this step</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form id="connect-form" action="/index.php?r=mainworkflows%2Fview&amp;id=<?= $mwf_id ?>" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="mainsteps-form">

            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group field-mainworkflows-step-name required">
                <label class="control-label" for="mainworkflows-step-name">Output</label>
                <select id="mainworkflows-step-name-dropdown" class="form-control" name="" aria-required="true">
                                    </select>

                <div class="help-block"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group field-mainworkflows-step-target required">
                <label class="control-label" for="mainworkflows-step-target">Output</label>
                <select id="mainworkflows-step-target-dropdown" class="form-control" name="" aria-required="true">
                                        <?php
                                            foreach ($mainstepsArray as $key => $value) {
                                                print "<option value='". $key ."'>".$value."</option>";
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>

                <div class="help-block"></div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <input type="hidden" id="mainsteps-mst_mwf_id" class="form-control" name="Mainsteps[mst_mwf_id]" value="<?= $mwf_id ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="Mainsteps[newRecord]" value="">
              <input type="hidden" id="mst_number" name="Mainsteps[mst_number]" value="">
              <input type="hidden" id="mst_name" name="Mainsteps[mst_name]" value="">
              <input type="hidden" id="mst_logicblock_id" name="Mainsteps[mst_lbk_id]" value="">
              <input type="hidden" id="old_mst_id" name="Mainsteps[old_mst_id]" value="">
              <input type="hidden" id="mainworkflows-mst_exit1" name="Mainsteps[mst_exit1]" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" id="mainworkflows-mst_exit2" name="Mainsteps[mst_exit2]" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" id="mainworkflows-mst_exit3" name="Mainsteps[mst_exit3]" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" id="mainworkflows-mst_exit4" name="Mainsteps[mst_exit4]" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" id="mainworkflows-mst_exit5" name="Mainsteps[mst_exit5]" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" id="mainworkflows-mst_exit6" name="Mainsteps[mst_exit6]" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" id="mainsteps-mst_data1" class="form-control" name="Mainsteps[mst_data1]" value="">
              <input type="hidden" id="mainsteps-mst_data2" class="form-control" name="Mainsteps[mst_data2]" value="">
              <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
              <!-- <button id="update-connection-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Before the form submits, I need to update a bunch of fields (`mainworkflows-mst_exit1` to `mainworkflows-mst_exit6`) based on the selection made in the drop-down.

I had this all working with the following code but now it seems the jQuery binding is not taking hold.

```
$('#connect-form').submit(function(e) {

// Convert output selection to the hidden 6 steps in the form
$('#connect-workflow-step-modal #mainworkflows-step-name-dropdown option:selected').each(function() {
    var target_step = $('#mainworkflows-step-target-dropdown').val();
    console.log('target_step:', target_step);

    $('#mainworkflows-mst_exit' + $(this).val() ).val(target_step);
});

console.log($(this).serializeArray());

return false; // Set to false while I debug
 });
```

Even when I insert the jQuery directly in the console, I get no errors but then when the form submits, it won't trigger the javascript. It simply submits. No binding.

To summarise:

I have a form that continues to submit even with a jQuery event handler on it that explicitly states '**`return false`**'.

I've also tried to target the click event by changing the submit button to a regular button but then I'm unable to trigger the form submit after with `jQuery.submit()`;

Comment: added an answer for you see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for your help but it turned out to be a simple matter of having two elements with the same id. Unfortunately, I can't mark my answer as the solution as it's been 'deleted from review' ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because Yii2's [**`Active Form javascript library`**](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/) provides you the events for the form bindings that it listens to.

### Available events are:

- beforeValidate.
- afterValidate.
- beforeValidateAttribute.
- afterValidateAttribute.
- beforeSubmit.
- ajaxBeforeSend.
- ajaxComplete.

### Using events

```
$('#contact-form').on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {

    //do your checks and if fail return false

    if (!confirm("Everything is correct. Submit?")) {
        return false;
    }

    //return true if all good 
    return true;
});
```

So in your case, you should use the **`beforeSubmit`** event

```
$('#connect-form').on('beforeSubmit',function(){
///do all your stuff
})
```